# Pandas: merge_asof() sum multiple rows / don't duplicate

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm working with two data sets that have different dates associated with each.  I want to merge them, but because the dates are not exact matches, I believe `merge_asof()` is the best way to go.

However, two things happen with a `merge_asof()` that are not ideal:

1. Numbers are duplicated.
2. Numbers are lost.

The following code is an example:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['1/15/2016','3/15/2016','5/15/2016','7/15/2016'])})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['1/1/2016','4/1/2016','5/1/2016','6/1/2016','7/1/2016']), 'num':[1,10,100,1000,10000]})

df_x = pd.merge_asof(df_a, df_b, on = 'date')
```

this yields:

```
        date    num
0 2016-01-15      1
1 2016-03-15      1
2 2016-05-15    100
3 2016-07-15  10000
```

but instead I would want:

```
        date    num
0 2016-01-15      1
1 2016-03-15      0
2 2016-05-15    110
3 2016-07-15  11000
```

...where sets of multiple rows that fall between dates are added up, and it isn't just that closest row that is chosen.

Is that possible with `merge_asof()` or should I look for another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting this question.  It prompted me to spend an educational couple of hours studying the `merge_asof` source.  I do not think that your solution can be improved considerably, but I would offer a couple of tweaks to speed it up a few percent.

```
# if we concat the original date vector, we will only need to merge once
df_ax = pd.concat([df_a, df_a.rename(columns={'date':'date1'})], axis=1)

# do the outer merge
df_m = pd.merge(df_ax, df_b, on='date', how='outer').sort_values(by='date')

# do a single rename, inplace
df_m.rename(columns={'date': 'datex', 'date1': 'date'}, inplace=True)

# fill the gaps to allow the groupby and sum
df_m['num'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_m['date'].fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)

# roll up the results.
x = df_m.groupby('date').num.sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the improvements.  I spent basically all day trying to figure this out and I'm still not satisfied.  I up-arrow'd your answer, but am not marking it as "the" answer just yet - I want to see if others have a more concise way of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking for the rows from B that are between the previous and current row of A. I can get the first and last index pretty easily with this:

```
# get the previous dates from A:
prev_dates = np.roll(df_a.date, 1)
prev_dates[0] = pd.to_datetime(0)

# get the first and last index of B:
start = np.searchsorted(df_b.date, prev_dates)
stop = np.searchsorted(df_b.date, df_a.date, side='right') - 1
```

And now I can use a little list comprehension to get my results:

```
>>> [df_b.num.values[begin:end+1].sum() for begin, end in zip(start, stop)]
[1, 0, 110, 11000]
```

Comment: Very nice!  One note: I don't think you need the `if/else` clause in the `list comprehension`, since a zero length list will sum to `0`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, answered my own question, but it seems a little hackish and I'd be interested in hearing other answers.  Also, this does *not* rely on `merge_asof()`.

Using the same DataFrames as above:

```
df_m = pd.merge(df_a, df_b, on = 'date', how = 'outer').sort_values(by = 'date')

df_a = df_a.rename(columns = {'date':'date1'})

df_m = pd.merge(df_m, df_a, left_on = 'date', right_on = 'date1', how = 'outer')

df_m['num'].fillna(0, inplace = True)
df_m['date1'].fillna(method = 'bfill', inplace = True)

x = df_m.groupby('date1').num.sum().reset_index().rename(columns = {'date1':'date'})
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to get the multiple rows, before aggregating:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df_a.assign(start_date = df_a.date.shift().fillna(pd.to_datetime(0)))
     .conditional_join(df_b.rename(columns={'date':'date_r'}),
                       # variable args of conditions
                       ('date', 'date_r', '>='), 
                       ('start_date', 'date_r', '<='), 
                       how = 'left')
     .groupby('date', as_index=False)
     .num
     .sum(numeric_only=True)
) 
        date      num
0 2016-01-15      1.0
1 2016-03-15      0.0
2 2016-05-15    110.0
3 2016-07-15  11000.0
```

Comment: Never even heard of pyjanitor, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which still uses `merge_asof()` along with [`duplicated()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html). I'll use the OP's example as a starting point

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['1/15/2016','3/15/2016','5/15/2016','7/15/2016'])})
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.to_datetime(['1/1/2016','4/1/2016','5/1/2016','6/1/2016','7/1/2016']), 'num':[1,10,100,1000,10000]})

df_x = pd.merge_asof(df_a, df_b, on = 'date')

# We have duplicate values in num column.  Set all but first match to 0 (or None, or...)
# Be careful to avoid nulls since Pandas sees those as values
df_x.loc[(df_x['num'].notnull()) & (df_x.duplicated('num')==True), 'num'] = 0
```

`df_x` now has the value:

```
        date    num
0 2016-01-15      1
1 2016-03-15      0
2 2016-05-15    100
3 2016-07-15  10000
```