# Pandas - Returning coordinates and value when conditional values are met

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using pandas and python 2.7.13 and I have been trying to import an excel file through pandas and compare data from two separate data frames using specified conditions to find when values from DF2 fall between two time values in DF1, and if the condition is met return a value from DF1 back onto DF2.

The data sets consist of DF2 a large database of records with a DateX (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM while DF1 is an export of staffing hours with the format of Start Time and End Time both formatted the same way then staff name.  We use a 3rd party system for our staffing and it isn't connected to our database and a report I am producing we need to see how specific employees are effecting performance.

Example data:

```
DF1
Employee:    Start Time:    End Time:
John Smith  1/1/2017 06:30 1/1/2017 18:30
Jane Smith  1/1/2017 06:30 1/1/2017 18:30
Tommy Boy  1/2/2017 06:30  1/2/2017 15:00

DF2
DateX:
1/1/2017 12:16
1/1/2017 06:43
1/2/2017 19:32
```

I have some experience with python but this is my first time using Pandas and numpy, my experience is purely project based on items I have attempted.  My current code reads as:

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'sample set.xlsx'

xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)

df1 = xl.parse('Sheet1')
df2 = xl.parse('Sheet2')

for i in df2['DateX']:
    if any(i >= df1['Start Time.1']) and any(i <= df1['End Time.1']):
        print i
```

I am only trying to print i currently to insure I am pulling the right number as I am using a limited data set as a test ground.  I run into two problems.  There can be multiple staff members from DF1 that worked the DateX from DF2, but this stops if there is even 1 match.

The other item is I accepted this and tried working out how could I get it to print out the match from df1['Employee'], but my efforts only produce the entire employee column.  This is a step of me learning in trying to then have it add the names that match next to the datex on DF2.

I am still continuing to attempt and read documentation and will update/close if I solve the problem on my own.  Thank you.

Comment: Digging through I have gotten further and adjusted for the for to start limiting my data. I first created a list with all dateX  known as datatimes.  Then i did 'for i in datetimes: print df1[(df1['Start Time.1'] < i) & (df1['End Time.1'] > i)]' got me to sort the list so you only see applicable data that it meets.  I now can see which employee names, but I need to apply that employee name to the df2 matching the dateX.

Comment: For each `DateX` value in `df2` do you want all the employee records from `df1` that have that `DateX` value between the `Start Time` and `End Time`? Can you print what a correct answer would look like?

Comment: A correct Answer based off the sample data above would be in DF2 `DateX: 1/1/2017 12:16 | John Smith | Jane Smith     1/1/2017 | John Smith | Jane Smith     1/2/2017 NAN` or just blank.  I have it now sorted and printing out the DateX and all matching employee names, but dont know how to do a .join or append to DF2 to have those match in in the columns next to the correct DateX

Comment: Your question sounds very similar to what I answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42372923/478288). You want to find the range of indices that correspond to your timestamps, and then perform whatever aggregation you need on the values in those ranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is similar to @Jay's but will return a list of employees for each time. Pandas unfortunately has no support for conditional joins like SQL. There is a new function `merge_asof` but it only returns a single value for each row which would not work for you.

The following will work but be very slow.

```
dfs = []

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    criteria = (row['Start Time'] <= df2['DateX']) & (df2['DateX'] <= row['End Time'])
    if not criteria.all():
        dfs.append(df2[criteria].assign(Employee=row['Employee']))

df2_all = pd.concat(dfs)
df2_agg = df2_all.groupby('DateX').agg(lambda x: ' | '.join(x.tolist()))
df2_final = df2_agg.reindex(df2.DateX)

                                     Employee
DateX                                        
2017-01-01 06:43:00  [John Smith, Jane Smith]
2017-01-01 12:16:00  [John Smith, Jane Smith]
2017-01-02 19:32:00                       NaN
```

Comment: Ted, your answer works directly out of the box, and produces the same answer as Jays at the df2_all stage. With your current end state I run into the problem that if I export it into excel to combine with the rest of my warehouse data, it has in one column u'[John Smith, Jane Smith]'.  At df2_all it looks removes the unicode marking.  I will try and solve myself, but how would I move if there are 2 names from ending up in 1 column to being in 2 columns associated with a said Datex.

Comment: @A.McMaster You can put all the values into one string instead of a list. See the change above. I used the pipe character to separate but you can use anything you want.

Comment: Ted, thank you!  I will continue to try and learn how to use pandas more but this is helping me complete a project for work without losing a bunch of time to 100% understanding the learning curve.  With this I was able to manipulate it in excel to fit my data set, re-enter and allow me to perform my correlation analysis.  Thank you.